# Nutch regex for Flickr

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm dealing with nutch and I want to crawl Flickr. I want to start from

```
   www.flickr.com/photos/tags
```

then select some tags (so I select some urls of the form www.flickr.com/photos/tags/tag_name). Alternatively, I can start from some tags that I choose, so my seed list will be

```
   www.flickr.com/photos/tags/beach 
   www.flickr.com/photos/tags/california
   www.flickr.com/photos/tags/japan
   ...
```

Now, these pages contain lots of images and my crawler must select these urls. Unfortunately, these urls have the form

```
   www.flickr.com/photos/user_name/photo_id
```

To summarize, I want to restrict my crawls to:

```
   www.flickr.com/photos/tags or if I start from particular tag www.flickr.com/photos/tags/tag_name
```

and

```
   www.flickr.com/photos/user_name/photo_id
```

How can I deal with this?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry guys. I removed the Hi everyone from the post :)

Comment: Validate the url with something like this `www\.flickr\.com/photos/(?:tags|[^/]*/photo_id)/?`

Answer (score 0):

Validate the url with something like this `www.flickr.com/photos/(?:tags|[^/]*/photo_id)/?`
                    – sln